# Can you add more entries to the Task View context menu in Win10?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu, task-manager, always-on-top

In Win10 when you <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> you get into the task view. I have an app that keeps crashing, but leaves its window 'on top'. This prevents me from using Task Manager to kill it, and I have to restart the machine - a pain!

I was wondering - is it possible to amend the Task View context menu (i.e., that which appears when you right-click on a 'task') to include some sort of shortcut to `TASKKILL`? The 'Close' on that menu does nothing in this instance.

Comment: A better solution is to fix what is crashing. You can do as you have done above, but yes, it is a pain. Fix the problem so it does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that. Just **make Task Manager always on top** and now once it has focus it'll appear above the offending app. If you can't enable always-on-top with the mouse then just open Task Manager with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> then turn it on by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>

The option is sticky, so after enabling it will stay on top the next time you open Task Manager

[image: Task Manager always-on-top]

In fact Windows 10's task manager is even more special in that no other app can be drawn over it. See [Is Task Manager a special kind of 'Always on Top' window for windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39246590/995714)

See also [How do I kill a program that hung with an always-on-top fullscreen window?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170425-00/?p=96035)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hotkey to a shortcut to [TASKKILL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill)

- Create a new shortcut by right clicking on the desktop then *New > Shortcut*
- Type the command `TASKKILL /F /IM yourapp.exe`, choose an appropriate name then press Enter
- Open the shortcut properties
- Type some hotkey to the ***"Shortcut key"*** field

Now anytime you want to kill that app just press the set hotkey from anywhere

You may need to change the `taskkill` command, for example to also kill the malfunctioning app along with all its child processes add the `/T` option, or you may need to filter the processes with some wildcards. For more information run `taskkill /?`

[image: Shortcut properties]